# How to run CellEndEdit when a cell value changes in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

The `CellEndEdit` event is running when I edit the datagridview cells, but when I print the data from the database to the DataGridView cell, `CellEndEdit` does not work:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "test";
```

How can I run `CellEndEdit`?

My code:

```
private void btnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int index = 2;
        int rc = gridView1.RowCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < rc; i++)
        {
            index++;
            string stk = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "STOKKODU").ToString();
            string beden = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "BEDEN").ToString();
            string mik = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "MIKTARI_2").ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = stk;
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = beden;
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = mik;
        }
        ExcelProje.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}


private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    object hucre = ExcelSayfa.Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1];
    Excel.Range bolge = ExcelSayfa.get_Range(hucre, hucre);
    bolge.Value2 = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
}
```

Comment: I dont understant :)

Comment: what you want to achieve? run cellendedit when you click something?

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = stk;

I want to run this code when I enter it.